# Несколько SQL запросов по диаграмме

Tags: sql, запрос, select

Нужно написать несколько вот SQL запросов к диаграмме. Условие запросов, диаграмма, а также мой вариант запросов здесь:

[image: Диаграмма]

[image: Условие]

Мой вариант:

1. SELECT Название специальности FROM Специальности WHERE Код специальности IN
   (SELECT Код специальности FROM Группы WHERE Код группы IN
   (SELECT Код группы FROM Студенты WHERE Код студента IN 
   (SELECT Код студента FROM Оценки WHERE Оценка IN
   (SELECT MAX(AVG(Оценка)) FROM Оценки))));
2. SELECT Название группы FROM Группы WHERE Код группы IN
   (SELECT Код группы FROM Студенты WHERE Код студента IN
   (SELECT Код студента FROM Оценки WHERE Оценка > 5));
3. SELECT Фамилия преподавателя FROM Преподаватели WHERE Код преподавателя IN
   (SELECT Код преподавателя FROM Оценки WHERE Оценка < 6);
4. SELECT ФИО, Размер стипендии FROM Студенты WHERE Код студента IN
   (SELECT Код студента FROM Оценки WHERE COUNT(Оценки = 4) > 2);

Comment: "Нет" на все 4 ответа.

Comment: Как тогда исправить, чтобы было правильно?

Comment: За Вас тут никто ничего делать не будет, не надейтесь.

Comment: Ну просто для кого-то будет не в тягость дать более развёрнутый ответ, чем просто "Нет".

Comment: Форма, в которой Вы задали вопрос крайне раздражает форумчан, которые могут Вам помочь (меня в том числе). Во-первых, есть смысл разбить исходный Ваш вопрос на четыре вопроса; Во-вторых прочесть это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (особенно по части учебных заданий). Для каждого из четырех отдельных вопросов уберите лишние таблицы. Избегайте прикладывать текст задания в виде картинки. Должна  быть четко видна Ваша попытка решения задачи и ход Ваших рассуждений. За Вас ничего делать не будут, а лишь подскажут куда нужно смотреть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. max(avg()) быть не может, нельзя вкладывать агрегатные функции. среднее нужно в разрезе специальности, значит должен быть group by по специальности. Было бы лучше посчитать средний балл в разрезе специальностей (собрав все join'ами, никаких IN). После отсортировать по нему и взять первую запись.
2. Требуется получить группы где *ВСЕ* студенты получили не менее 5. Ваш запрос выберет группы где *хотя бы один* студент получил такой балл. Требуется опять же join с последующим group by, который соберет минимальные оценки в группе и в having отфильтровать где минимальная оценка не ниже 6.
3. (который на самом деле 4). Как и в первом случае получите преподавателей у которых хотя бы одна оценка меньше 6, т.е. полностью противоположный результат. Нужен либо not exists/not in, который проверит отсутствие оценок выше 6. либо опять же group by, по преподавателю с проверкой в having, что максимальная оценка ниже 6.
4. (который 3). Я бы слово "Уменьшить" воспринял как необходимость изменить содержимое таблицы, а не просто вывести результат. `COUNT(Оценки = 4)` даст количество записей где Оценка не null, никакой проверки на =4 не произойдет, ибо count считает количество не null значений (а оператор `=` возвращает всегда не null и то только в mysql, в других БД так писать вообще нельзя). Кроме того count() в предложении where быть не может, потому что where применяется до группировки. Надо получить студентов с требуемыми оценками. Опять же group by по студенту, отсев только нужных оценок в where и проверка count(*)>2 в having. А потом не забыть все таки посчитать 80% от стипендии и либо вывести, либо использовать в update (смотря как вы понимаете слово "Уменьшить")

P.S. Изучать sql чисто на бумаге практически бесполезно, создайте БД (можно на каком нибудь online сервисе), заполните тестовыми данными. И проверяйте запросы на работоспособность и требуемый результат.

Comment: @Corvus, ИМХО есть смысл принять ответ от Mike (там у Вас есть кнопочка "принять" с зеленой галочкой) - по тому как Вы сформулировали вопрос, вряд ли Вы дождетесь более полного и адекватного разбора Ваших проблем.